# Searchable Dictionary V2 Sample How to Perform rawQuery on the Dictionary Database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, dictionary

I would like to perform a rawQuery on the dictionary database inside the method protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in WordActivity.java

It should be something like db.rawQuery() but I can't figure how to find the db instance inside the method...

Answer (score 0):

Create your database helper class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper`

create instance of your helper passing the context from your activity and start accessing database with `getWritableDatabase()` API which gives you `SQLiteDatabase` instance where you can execute `rawQuery`

Comment: There is already a SQLiteOpenHelper class created in the sample. I just don't know how to access to it from WordActivity class to perform rawQuery.

You can view all the sample's source code here
ftp://ftp.gunadarma.ac.id/android/sdk/sdk_310712/docs/resources/samples/SearchableDictionary/src/com/example/android/searchabledict